# understand thread interference (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to understand what thread interference is.
This is an explanation about thread interference from Java official site.

> Thread A: Retrieve c.
> Thread B: Retrieve c.
> Thread A: Increment retrieved value; result is 1.
> Thread B: Decrement retrieved value; result is -1.
> Thread A: Store result in c; c is now 1.
> Thread B: Store result in c; c is now -1.

so I added codes to see c's changes.

In the picture(4th line),
Shouldn't **1th decrement:(Retrieve  C) 0** be -1? why it's 0?

Also, if you see this below result, 2th decrement:(Retrieve C) is -1.

I think 2th decrement(Decreased C) should be -2, but it's still -1.

I don't understand. Can someone explain my reslt?

**2th decrement:(Retrieve  C) -1**

**2th decrement(Decreased C) -1**

[image]

```
public class Counter {
private int c = 0;
public void increment(){
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
        System.out.println(i + "th increment:(Retrieve  C) " + c);
        c++;
        System.out.println(i + "th increment:(Increased C) " + c);
    }
}
public void decrement(){
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
        System.out.println(i + "th decrement:(Retrieve  C) " + c);
        c--;
        System.out.println(i + "th decrement(Decreased C) " + c);
    }
}
public int getC(){
    return c;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    Counter c = new Counter();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
        c.increment();
    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
        c.decrement();

    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

}
```

}

Comment: Your use of `println()` doesn't show you what you maybe think it shows. Printing `c` _before_ the `c++` operation does not necessarily tell you what value was fetched _by_ the `c++` operation: The other thread could have changed `c` in between the print, and the ++. Likewise, Printing `c` _after_ the `c++` operation is not guaranteed to tell you what value was stored _by_ the `c++`. Same reason: The other thread could have changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `c++;` actually does three things, one after the other.

1. It reads the value of `c`.
2. It increments what it saw.
3. It saves the new value back into `c`.

The operations is not atomic, which means there's no guarantee that `c` won't change independently while it's doing that.  Likewise for `c--;`.

So while you've got two threads doing similar things to the same variable `c`, it's very likely that one of them is going to change `c` while the other is doing its work.  And that seems to be what you're seeing.

In fact, by printing `c` in both threads, you're increasing the likelihood that one of the threads will change the value of `c` between the times when the other thread prints its two messages.

Comment: Thank you. So printing 'c' is not a good idea to track 'c' because threads keep changing 'c'. Then how this code always shows the same result(0) at the end?

Comment: Well, the explanation that you copied from the site has an example where it finishes up at -1 instead.  I guess 0 is the most likely value for it to end up with, because it would indicate that thread B overwrites A's change exactly as often as thread A overwrites B's change.  But I'd be quite surprised if it finishes up with 0 every time you run it.

Comment: A race condition isn't the only problem this code is suffering from.

Answer (score 1):

The term 'interference' has no official meaning. Your code is suffering from 2 problems

1. race condition: because the read and write aren't atomic, and therefore you can run into lost updates.
2. data race: because the access to the 'c' variable isn't synchronized, there is no happens-before edge. To gain a deeper understanding, you need to dig into the Java Memory Model.

Both problems can easily be solved by making 'c' an AtomicInteger and use the increment/decrement methods.